# Send keyboard commands to window under cursor

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, cursor

Is there any way that I can redirect keyboard commands to be sent to whichever window is under the mouse cursor, instead of to the active window? I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.

I tried using the in built windows option to automatically make the window which is under the cursor active, but this option has a short delay which annoys me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send keystroke to window under cursor ( prevent focus stealing )](http://superuser.com/questions/453169/send-keystroke-to-window-under-cursor-prevent-focus-stealing).